# Installing Regripper on Ubuntu 19.10 gives error Can't locate Parse/Win32Registry.pm

Tags: 19.10

I am trying to install RegRipper on my Ubuntu 19.10 desktop machine. RegRipper is a program that can analyze registry files from Windows. Its avaible here: https://github.com/keydet89/RegRipper2.8.git

**First install Git**

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

**Install Win32Registry**

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Parse::Win32Registry'
```

**Install Regripper**

```
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://github.com/keydet89/RegRipper2.8.git
sudo mv RegRipper2.8 regripper
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER regripper
```

**Make shell**

```
# Fix end of line
cd /opt/regripper
sudo cat rip.pl | sed 's|\r$||g' > /tmp/riplin0.pl

# Now fix the first line so linux perl executed
sudo cat /tmp/riplin0.pl | sed "s| c:\\\\perl\\\\bin\\\\perl.exe|`which perl`|" > /tmp/riplin1.pl

# Fix the backslash before the plugins directory
sudo cat /tmp/riplin1.pl | sed 's|plugins\\\\|plugins/|' > riplin.pl

# Make executable
sudo chmod +x riplin.pl
```

When I now try to execute riplin I get a error:

```
opt/regripper$ ./riplin.pl -l
```

> Can't locate Parse/Win32Registry.pm in @INC (you may need to install
>   the Parse::Win32Registry module) (@INC contains:
>   /home/xxx/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.1/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
>   /home/xxx/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.1
>   /home/xxx/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
>   /home/xxx/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28
>   /usr/share/perl/5.28 /home/xxx/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0
>   /home/xxx/perl5/lib/perl5/5.28.0/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at
>   ./riplin.pl line 29.
>       BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./riplin.pl line 29.

So the error is *Can't locate Parse/Win32Registry.pm*. On line 29 of riplin.pl it says *use Parse::Win32Registry qw(:REG_);*

**riplin.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rip - RegRipper, CLI version
# Use this utility to run a plugins file or a single plugin against a Reg
# hive file.
# 
# Output goes to STDOUT
# Usage: see "_syntax()" function
#
# Change History
#   20190318 - modified code to allow the .exe to be run from anywhere within the file system
#   20190128 - added Time::Local, modifications to module Key.pm
#   20180406 - added "-uP" switch to update profiles
#   20130801 - added File::Spec support, for cross-platform compat.
#   20130716 - added 'push(@INC,$str);' line based on suggestion from
#              Hal Pomeranz to support Linux compatibility
#   20130425 - added alertMsg() functionality, updated to v2.8
#   20120506 - updated to v2.5 release
#   20110516 - added -s & -u options for TLN support
#   20090102 - updated code for relative path to plugins dir
#   20080419 - added '-g' switch (experimental)
#   20080412 - added '-c' switch
#
# copyright 2013-2019 Quantum Analytics Research, LLC
# Author: H. Carvey, keydet89@yahoo.com
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
use strict;
use Parse::Win32Registry qw(:REG_);
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::Local;
use File::Spec;


# Included to permit compiling via Perl2Exe
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry/Key.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry/Entry.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry/Value.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry/File.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry/Win95/File.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Parse/Win32Registry/Win95/Key.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Encode.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Encode/Byte.pm";
#perl2exe_include "Encode/Unicode.pm";
#perl2exe_include "utf8.pm";
#perl2exe_include "unicore/Heavy.pl";
#perl2exe_include "unicore/To/Upper.pl";

my %config;
Getopt::Long::Configure("prefix_pattern=(-|\/)");
GetOptions(\%config,qw(reg|r=s file|f=s csv|c guess|g user|u=s sys|s=s plugin|p=s update|uP list|l help|?|h));

# Code updated 20090102
my @path;
my $str = $0;
($^O eq "MSWin32") ? (@path = split(/\\/,$0))
                   : (@path = split(/\//,$0));
$str =~ s/($path[scalar(@path) - 1])//;

# Suggested addition by Hal Pomeranz for compatibility with Linux
#push(@INC,$str);
# code updated 20190318
my $plugindir;
($^O eq "MSWin32") ? ($plugindir = $str."plugins/")
                   : ($plugindir = File::Spec->catfile("plugins"));
#my $plugindir = $str."plugins/";
#my $plugindir = File::Spec->catfile("plugins");
#print "Plugins Dir = ".$plugindir."\n";
# End code update
my $VERSION = "2\.8_20190318";
my @alerts = ();

if ($config{help} || !%config) {
    _syntax();
    exit;
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
if ($config{list}) {
    my @plugins;
    opendir(DIR,$plugindir) || die "Could not open $plugindir: $!\n";
    @plugins = readdir(DIR);
    closedir(DIR);

    my $count = 1; 
    print "Plugin,Version,Hive,Description\n" if ($config{csv});
    foreach my $p (@plugins) {
        next unless ($p =~ m/\.pl$/);
        my $pkg = (split(/\./,$p,2))[0];
#       $p = $plugindir.$p;
        $p = File::Spec->catfile($plugindir,$p);
        eval {
            require $p;
            my $hive    = $pkg->getHive();
            my $version = $pkg->getVersion();
            my $descr   = $pkg->getShortDescr();
            if ($config{csv}) {
                print $pkg.",".$version.",".$hive.",".$descr."\n";
            }
            else {
                print $count.". ".$pkg." v.".$version." [".$hive."]\n";
#               printf "%-20s %-10s %-10s\n",$pkg,$version,$hive;
                print  "   - ".$descr."\n\n";
                $count++;
            }
        };
        print "Error: $@\n" if ($@);
    }
    exit;
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
if ($config{update}) {
    my @plugins;
    opendir(DIR,$plugindir) || die "Could not open $plugindir: $!\n";
    @plugins = readdir(DIR);
    closedir(DIR);
# hash of lists to hold plugin names    
    my %files = ();

    foreach my $p (@plugins) {
        next unless ($p =~ m/\.pl$/);
# $pkg = name of plugin     
        my $pkg = (split(/\./,$p,2))[0];
#       $p = $plugindir.$p;
        $p = File::Spec->catfile($plugindir,$p);
        eval {
            require $p;
            my $hive    = $pkg->getHive();
            my @hives = split(/,/,$hive);
            foreach my $h (@hives) {
                my $lch = lc($h);
                $lch =~ s/\.dat$//;
                $lch =~ s/^\s+//;

                push(@{$files{$lch}},$pkg);

            }

        };
        print "Error: $@\n" if ($@);
    }

# once hash of lists is populated, print files      
    foreach my $f (keys %files) {
        my $filepath = $plugindir."\\".$f;
        open(FH,">",$filepath) || die "Could not open ".$filepath." to write: $!";

        for my $i (0..$#{$files{$f}}) {
            next if ($files{$f}[$i] =~ m/tln$/);
            print FH $files{$f}[$i]."\n";
        }

        close(FH);  
    }
    exit;
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
if ($config{file}) {
# First, check that a hive file was identified, and that the path is
# correct
    my $hive = $config{reg};
    die "You must enter a hive file path/name.\n" if ($hive eq "");
#   die $hive." not found.\n" unless (-e $hive);

    my %plugins = parsePluginsFile($config{file});
    if (%plugins) {
        logMsg("Parsed Plugins file.");
    }
    else {
        logMsg("Plugins file not parsed.");
        exit;
    }
    foreach my $i (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %plugins) {
        eval {
#           require "plugins/".$plugins{$i}."\.pl";
            my $plugin_file = File::Spec->catfile($plugindir,$plugins{$i}.".pl");
            require $plugin_file;
            $plugins{$i}->pluginmain($hive);
        };
        if ($@) {
            logMsg("Error in ".$plugins{$i}.": ".$@);
        }
        logMsg($plugins{$i}." complete.");
        rptMsg("-" x 40);
    }
    printAlerts();
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
if ($config{reg} && $config{guess}) {
# Attempt to guess which kind of hive we have
    my $hive = $config{reg};
    die "You must enter a hive file path/name.\n" if ($hive eq "");
#   die $hive." not found.\n" unless (-e $hive);

    my $reg;
    my $root_key;
    my %guess = guessHive($hive);

    foreach my $g (keys %guess) {
        ::rptMsg(sprintf "%-8s = %-2s",$g,$guess{$g});
    }
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
if ($config{plugin}) {
# First, check that a hive file was identified, and that the path is
# correct
    my $hive = $config{reg};
    die "You must enter a hive file path/name.\n" if ($hive eq "");
#   die $hive." not found.\n" unless (-e $hive);    

# check to see if the plugin exists
    my $plugin = $config{plugin};
#   my $pluginfile = $plugindir.$config{plugin}."\.pl";
    my $pluginfile = File::Spec->catfile($plugindir,$config{plugin}."\.pl");
    die $pluginfile." not found.\n" unless (-e $pluginfile);

    eval {
        require $pluginfile;
        $plugin->pluginmain($hive);
    };
    if ($@) {
        logMsg("Error in ".$pluginfile.": ".$@);
    }   
    printAlerts();
}

sub _syntax {
    print<< "EOT";
Rip v.$VERSION - CLI RegRipper tool 
Rip [-r Reg hive file] [-f plugin file] [-p plugin module] [-l] [-h]
Parse Windows Registry files, using either a single module, or a plugins file.

  -r Reg hive file...Registry hive file to parse
  -g ................Guess the hive file (experimental)
  -f [profile].......use the plugin file (default: plugins/plugins)
  -p plugin module...use only this module
  -l ................list all plugins
  -c ................Output list in CSV format (use with -l)
  -s system name.....Server name (TLN support)
  -u username........User name (TLN support)
  -uP ...............Update profiles
  -h.................Help (print this information)

Ex: C:\\>rip -r c:\\case\\system -f system
    C:\\>rip -r c:\\case\\ntuser.dat -p userassist
    C:\\>rip -l -c

All output goes to STDOUT; use redirection (ie, > or >>) to output to a file\.

copyright 2019 Quantum Analytics Research, LLC
EOT
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub logMsg {
    print STDERR $_[0]."\n";
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub rptMsg {
    binmode STDOUT,":utf8";
    if ($config{sys} || $config{user}) {
        my @vals = split(/\|/,$_[0],5);
        my $str = $vals[0]."|".$vals[1]."|".$config{sys}."|".$config{user}."|".$vals[4];
        print $str."\n";
    }
    else {
        print $_[0]."\n";
    }
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub alertMsg {
    push(@alerts,$_[0]);
}

sub printAlerts {
    if (scalar(@alerts) > 0) {
#       print "\n";
#       print "Alerts\n";
#       print "-" x 40,"\n";
        foreach (@alerts) {
            print $_."\n";
        }
    }
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# parsePluginsFile()
# Parse the plugins file and get a list of plugins
#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub parsePluginsFile {
    my $file = $_[0];
    my %plugins;
# Parse a file containing a list of plugins
# Future versions of this tool may allow for the analyst to 
# choose different plugins files    
#   my $pluginfile = $plugindir.$file;
    my $pluginfile = File::Spec->catfile($plugindir,$file);
    if (-e $pluginfile) {
        open(FH,"<",$pluginfile);
        my $count = 1;
        while(<FH>) {
            chomp;
            next if ($_ =~ m/^#/ || $_ =~ m/^\s+$/);
#           next unless ($_ =~ m/\.pl$/);
            next if ($_ eq "");
            $_ =~ s/^\s+//;
            $_ =~ s/\s+$//;
            $plugins{$count++} = $_; 
        }
        close(FH);
        return %plugins;
    }
    else {
        return undef;
    }
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# guessHive()
# 
#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub guessHive {
    my $hive = shift;
    my $reg;
    my $root_key;
    my %guess;
    eval {
        $reg = Parse::Win32Registry->new($hive);
      $root_key = $reg->get_root_key;
    };
    $guess{unknown} = 1 if ($@);

# Check for SAM
    eval {
        $guess{sam} = 1 if (my $key = $root_key->get_subkey("SAM\\Domains\\Account\\Users"));
    };
# Check for Software    
    eval {
        $guess{software} = 1 if ($root_key->get_subkey("Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion") &&
                $root_key->get_subkey("Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"));
    };

# Check for System  
    eval {
        $guess{system} = 1 if ($root_key->get_subkey("MountedDevices") &&
                $root_key->get_subkey("Select"));
    };

# Check for Security    
    eval {
        $guess{security} = 1 if ($root_key->get_subkey("Policy\\Accounts") &&
                $root_key->get_subkey("Policy\\PolAdtEv"));
    };
# Check for NTUSER.DAT  
    eval {
        $guess{ntuser} = 1 if ($root_key->get_subkey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion"));

    };  

    return %guess;
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# getTime()
# Translate FILETIME object (2 DWORDS) to Unix time, to be passed
# to gmtime() or localtime()
#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub getTime($$) {
    my $lo = shift;
    my $hi = shift;
    my $t;

    if ($lo == 0 && $hi == 0) {
        $t = 0;
    } else {
        $lo -= 0xd53e8000;
        $hi -= 0x019db1de;
        $t = int($hi*429.4967296 + $lo/1e7);
    };
    $t = 0 if ($t < 0);
    return $t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can install with apt

```
apt-get install -y libparse-win32registry-perl -y
```